# Как получить id инпута?

Tags: python, django

Допустим, у меня есть в шаблоне

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="{{product.id}}" >
```

Как мне получить значение id данного инпута в views.py? Например, что бы записать id в `args['id_input']` могу получить поле value:

```
args['id_input']=request.POST.get("text", "")
```

А как получить поле id?

Comment: Никак, браузер передаёт только значения атрибутов name и value.

Answer (score 0):

Можете например в HTML рядом с этим полем положить спрятанное поле,

`<input type='hidden' name="product_id" value="{{product.id}}"/>`

На стороне Flask можно получить по имени поля - `args['id_input']=request.POST.get("product_id", "")`

Разумеется в этом случае атрибут `id` лучше у поля по имени `text` убрать.